# How to get the text of the second button on WPF application

Tags: c#-4.0, automation, coded-ui-tests

I am using CodedUI to automate on a WPF application, I have 2 buttons in a form, I want to verify the text of each button. But when running only have passed script. Because The actual result of the second script is always the actual of the first button. So how I get the second text to verify? Please help me.

(I saw they are the same AutomationID when I record)

Answer (score 0):

Check the search properties and search configurations of the buttons in the uitest file.  If the properties are ambiguous, codedui will find the same button each time.  If you have access to the application source, try giving the buttons unique friendly names.